# Comparing char in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, comparison

This is my text file that I'm taking data from

```
10
wood      8
gold      7
silver    5
gold      9
wood      1
silver    1
silver    9
wood      3
gold      5
wood      7
```

I'm supposed to find goods with the same name and add all of their amounts, so final result should be wood=19; gold=21; silver=15. This is what I did so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream read("data.txt");
    int n;
    read >> n;
    char name[10][n]; // 10 symbols are given for items name
    int amount[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
    read.ignore(80, '\n');
    read.get(name[i], 10);
    read >> amount[i];
    }

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(int d=1; d<n; d++)
    {
    if(name[i]==name[d] && i!=d)
    {

    }
    }
}
    return 1;
}
```

Problem so far is that `name[i]==name[d]` doesn't react even is for example `name[i]="wood"` and `name[d]="wood"`

Comment: Use `std::string` in place of `char[]` and your sanity will thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, we tend to use [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) over `char[]`. The first has the equality operator overloaded, thus your code shall work. With the latter, you need [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to achieve your goal.

Now your code could like this (I used std::vector, but you can use an array of string, but I do not recommend it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("data.txt");
    int n;
    infile >> n;
    vector<string> name(n);
    int amount[n], i = 0;
    while (infile >> name[i] >> amount[i])
    {
        cout << name[i] << " " << amount[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
    // do your logic
    return 0;
}
```

---

By the way, you could use [`std::pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/), to make your code more readable, where the first member would be the name and the second the amount.

---

Unrelated to your problem, `main()` tends to `return 0;` when everything is fine, whereas you return 1.

PS: Here is a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile("data.txt");
    int n;
    infile >> n;
    vector<string> name(n);
    int amount[n], i = 0;
    while (infile >> name[i] >> amount[i])
    {
//        cout << name[i] << " " << amount[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }


    vector< pair<string, int> > result;
    bool found;
    for(int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i)
    {
        found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < result.size(); ++j)
        {
            if(name[i] == result[j].first)
            {
                result[j].second += amount[i];
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
        {
            result.push_back({name[i], amount[i]});
        }
    }

    cout << "RESULTS:\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); ++i)
        cout << result[i].first << " " << result[i].second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall -std=c++0x main.cpp 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
RESULTS:
wood 19
gold 21
silver 15
```

Comment: How do I read with string from file? I get `error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::get(std::string&, int)` at the line `read.get(name[i], 10);` if I change char to string.

Comment: Problem is that right now I'm preparing for my school exam and I don't know if we will be allowed to use additional libraries, so I'd rather learn how to make this code work without them

Comment: OK then @MahigYahok, you can use `strcmp()`, as I am mentioning in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, gcc is know to accept it but Variable Length Arrays are not supported in C++, so this line:

```
char name[10][n]; // 10 symbols are given for items name
```

is not conformant and should have given at least a warning.

The C++ way to deal with array whose dimension is only known at run time is to use `std::vector`.

But your real problem is that neither a raw char array nor a pointer to char have an overriden `==` operator (it is not possible for arrays or pointers), so in your `name[i]==name[d]` you are actually comparing the addresses because the arrays decay to pointers to their first element when used in expressions. So your test is the same as `if (&name[i][0] == &name[d][0)` and cannot give expected result.

You can use `strcmp` to compare null terminated char arrays (also known as C strings) or better use `std::string` which has an overidden `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

The char[] == operator you're using is comparing pointer values, rather than string comparison values.  ie you're comparing the position of the first characters in memory.

As a side note,  char name[10][n]; is invalid; as that n would have to be a compile time constant.  I'd suggest std::vector as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to add the number then you can use an [unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). It is similar to the hash table in java.